# Cannot instantiate object in Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good morning all,

I am currently trying to instantiate a gameobject in Unity. I get no errors, but playing my game results in no enemies spawning. This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnEnemies : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject defaultenemy;
    public GameObject burstenemy;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Instantiate(defaultenemy);
    }

}
```

I've tried multiple different things, like adding in a position and rotation to the instantiate method, but there is no change. I've also made sure to add my enemy prefabs in the inspector for the script. The game works fine, but i cannot see the enemy and it doesn't appear in the explorer.

Any help is appreciated :-)

EDIT: Turns out i had to attach the script to an empty game object. Solved!

Comment: is SpawnEnemies running?

Comment: is that `SpawnEnemies` attached to an active GameObject in the scene?

Comment: Add a `Debug.Log` to print the return value of `Instantiate`. If you don't see it in the console, then your script isn't running. If you do see it, then it should tell you if Instantiate failed and then you can investigate why.